# how to run python script through Mininet host?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, mininet, pox

I have a problem running python script via host command inside the Mininet topology code. The following is my code

```
(net.get('h0')).cmd('sudo python arp_ping.py')
```

The Mininet executed without errors but it is not running the script.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to run it through your host via xterm.

In mininet:

> xterm h0

Then (be in the right directory):

> ./arp_ping.py

Comment: I need to add it inside the code to be able to send multiple ARP requests from different hosts simultaneously